# What is the difference between whom and whomever, if any?

Tags: pronouns

[**Source**](https://www.facebook.com/Ssc.Cgl.English/posts/569758549771968)

You can give the money to "whoever" you like.

A. Whoever
B. Whomever
C. Whom
D. No improvement

Book says C but I am confused between B and C

Comment: They are all splendid English words. We need context to form our opinions. Sentences, please.

Comment: This is an example question from an Indian government exam that assesses the English proficiency of candidates for jobs in the bureaucracy.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Which option do you feel is the best fit here?

Comment: @గణేష్రెడ్డి The book is wrong. The answer is B, _whomever._

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is B, "whomever":

> You can give the money to **whomever** you like.

The objective case is required because *who* is the object of the verb *like* in the embedded clause *whomever you like.* That embedded clause in turn is the object of the preposition *to.*

It is a common error, in a sentence like this one, to believe that the preposition *to* governs the case of the pronoun. Instead, it is the structure of the embedded clause that determines the case of the pronoun. For instance, if the sentence instead were:

> You can give the money to **whoever** comes first.

...the *subjective* case *whoever* would be correct, because here *who* is the subject of the verb *come* in the embedded clause that is the object of *to.*

*Neal Whitman* of *Literal-minded* has written a piece for *Grammar Girl* on this subject, and for those who prefer a spoken answer, a link to the podcast is [**here.**](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whoever-or-whomever)

Mr Whitman's own blog features an entertaining piece on the subject as well, and those who are interested may read it to learn why it is entitled [***Whomever* Is Never Actually Right.**](https://literalminded.wordpress.com/2007/10/21/whomever-is-never-actually-right/)

---

<sup>(Note that in modern spoken English, the objective *whoever* is often used no matter what case is called for by an embedded clause, and the "requirements" of formal grammar should not trouble anyone who chooses to use it.)</sup>